# A random sample from triangular distribution: R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I would like to generate numbers from a triangular distribution with three parameters: a, b, c where c in my case is defined as (a+b)/2.
Let's say I have a vector `x`:

```
x <- c(1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,5,-5,11,-11,12,-12,13,-13)
```

And I want to generate as many new values as there are negative numbers in vector x. So further I can replace negative values with numbers generated from triangular distribution.

```
library(triangle)
c = abs(x[x<0])/2
sample <- rtriangle(length(a[which(a<0)]), 0, abs(x[x<0]),c)
```

Obviously this does not work, as I get a warning message:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In if (a > c | b < c) return(rep(NaN, times = n)) :
>    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   2: In if (a != c) { :
>    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   3: In p[i] * (b - a) :
>    longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>   4: In p[i] <- a + sqrt(p[i] * (b - a) * (c - a)) :
>    number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>   5: In (1 - p[j]) * (b - a) :
>    longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>   6: In p[j] <- b - sqrt((1 - p[j]) * (b - a) * (b - c)) :
>    number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Parameter `a` is 0, but `b` and `c` are not single numbers. It is not clear to me how are you trying to sample.

Comment: From the help of `rtriangle`: `a, b, and c may be appropriate length vectors except in the case of rtriangle.`

Comment: I would like to get a vector (vector length correspond to a number of negative numbers in vector **x**) of numbers sampled from a triangular distribution. I want to sample in a range from _a_ (_a = 0_) to _b_ (_b is an absolute value of a negative element in a vector_**x**) and parameter _c_ is: _c = b/2_.

Comment: I do not understand how `rtriangle: a, b, and c may be appropriate length vectors except in the case of rtriangle.` is a limitation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `rtriangle` does not take vectors as input, you could create a vector evaluating every element of a vector using `sapply` like this:

```
x <- c(1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,5,-5,11,-11,12,-12,13,-13)

library("triangle")

sample = sapply(abs(x[x<0]), function(x){ rtriangle(1,0,x,x/2) })

> sample
[1] 0.6514940 0.6366981 1.8598445 0.9866790 1.7517438 2.9444719 4.1537113 2.2315813
```

You will get one random sample for 8 different triangular distributions.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what your comment was about. Looks like the answer helped.